# Python Paho MQTT subscriber getting stuck - influxdb write

Tags: python, mqtt, paho, influxdb-python

I published to a topic using paho mqtt module and I subscribed to it from another program.
I am publishing 10000 messages that the publisher is able to send in around 2 seconds. In the subscriber, I'm getting the message and writing the value to influxdb. After around 2000 records, the MQTT subscriber is halting and waiting till time.sleep() finishes.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt #import the client1
import time
from datetime import datetime
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, Dialect, WriteOptions
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS

org = "my-ord"
bucket = "Bucket1"
token = "my-token"
client = InfluxDBClient(url="http://localhost:8086", token=token, org=org)

write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
query_api = client.query_api()
#Function to write the record to influx
def update_db(point):
     
    write_api.write(bucket=bucket, record=point)
    print("Point written")

msg_count = 0   
#On message callback function
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global msg_count
    msg_count+=1
    print("message received " ,str(message.payload))

    _point1 = Point("mqtt2").tag("message","message").field("datapt",str(message.payload))

    update_db(_point1)

    print(msg_count)
#This is the Subscriber
ip = "localhost" 
client = mqtt.Client("P2")
client.on_message=on_message
client.connect(ip) 
client.loop_start()
client.subscribe("influx")

time.sleep(180)

client.loop_stop()
print(msg_count)
```

The publisher publishes 10000 messages within a second. Without the influx write command, the code runs till the end. When I include the write, the subscriber stops after around 2000 messages. What should I change to make it work?

Comment: It looks like you are using QOS=0 (default) which means there is no guarantee of delivery; some brokers impose limits on the number of inflight messages (e.g. mosquitto defaults to 20) and additional messages may be dropped (even at higher QOS levels in mosquitto the `max_queued_messages` defaults to 1000 which you may well hit). Check your broker settings and the broker log; I'd guess it is dropping messages.

Comment: Do you mean that the code is stopping between the first and second `print()` in the `on_message()` callback?

Answer (score 0):

The influx write will be a blocking call, you should not be making blocking calls in the MQTT Client callbacks as they prevent the client from handling new incoming messages.

If you need to do blocking IO as a result of the incoming message you should be handing that work off to a separate thread.